# Qt-Creator - Trouble resizing widgets within QTabWidget

Tags: qt, resize, widget

I am having trouble horizontally resizing a `QTableWidget` within a `QTabWidget`.

If the `QTableWidget` is on its own in my `MainWindow`, it resizes horizontally without any problems (or limits). As soon as I place the `QTableWidget` inside the `QTabWidget` I seem to hit a maximum width for the `QTablewidget`. I can resize it horizontally, but only so far. I do not seem to have this limitation vertically.

My `sizePolicies` are set to `Expanding` for both directions.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I took some screenshots to try and clear things up. The 'QTableWidget' that is not within the 'QTabWidget' stretches much further horizontally.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you achieve the resizing effect of your `QTableWidget` in the `MainWindow`?

Comment: I dropped the QTableWidget into MainWindow and set the layout to vertical.

Comment: Did you set the maximum size of height on your `QTablewidget`?

Comment: The maximum size is set to 16777215 (the max) for both the width and weight.

Comment: Sry but I am still having trouble understanding your situation. Perhaps you could add some pictures.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far Tay, please see the edit I made to the original post with images (I could only link to two because of my reputation). The first is an overview of the problem. The bottom `QTableWidget` has no limit to its horizontal stretching, unlike the one inside the `QTabWidget`. The second link has an image of my Object Inspector (incase it helps). Thanks!

Comment: I can only reproduce your situation in 2 ways: [1] Set the max size of the `QTableWidget` in `QTabWidget`; [2] set some `layoutRightMargin` on the layout of `QTabWidget`. Since you said it's not [1], you can check if you accidently set the margin on the layout. Otherwise, delete the troublesome `QTableWidget` and add a new one to see if it's still the same.

Comment: Deleting it seems to have solved it! (I thought I had done so before...) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I've seen something similar before, probably some buggy stuff inside Qt Designer.